# Creating a spiral shape from 3d cubes - javafx

Tags: javafx, 3d, cube, spiral, helix

I am a lot of confused about how i create a complex 3d model in javafx.
More specifically, I want create a spiral or helix which is a group of many cubes.

I have the mathematical type to create my points for the mesh:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        v1=Math.sin(pi*i*0.125)*150;
        v2=i*50;
        v3=Math.cos(pi*i*0.125)*150;           
        mesh.getPoints().addAll((float)v1,(float) v2,(float) v3); 
        mesh.getPoints().addAll((float)v1,(float) v2,(float) - v3);
        mesh.getPoints().addAll((float)v1,(float) -v2,(float) v3);
        mesh.getPoints().addAll((float)v1,(float) -v2,(float)- v3);

        mesh.getPoints().addAll((float)-v1,(float) v2,(float) v3);
        mesh.getPoints().addAll((float)-v1,(float) v2,(float) -v3);
        mesh.getPoints().addAll((float)-v1,(float) -v2,(float) v3);
        mesh.getPoints().addAll((float)-v1,(float) -v2,(float) -v3);

    }
```

But when i try to write the faces , output is awful. 
How faces must be written?

Answer (score 0):

What you have shown are just the points. What about the faces?
Have a look here: https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz
This may help to get you going.

Comment: FXyz is a very good and helpful guide.. I found a lot of information! Thank you! 
But what i need to do in general for my application, is to create custom 3d shapes. So I decided to create a java class for each user-defined shape. Correct me if I am wrong.